# Syntax Directed Translation Scheme for Postfix to Infix Notation

Tags: compilers, parsers, syntax-trees

I'm reading *Compilers Principles, Techniques and Tools* textbook and I encountered a problem from exercise 2.3

We have to construct a syntax-directed translation scheme that translates arithmetic expression from postfix notation into infix notation. I constructed a scheme the following way.

```
expr -> expr expr + | expr expr - | expr expr * | expr expr / | digit
```

into

```
expr -> expr {print('+')} expr +
      | expr {print('-')} expr -
      | {print('(')} expr {print(') * (')} expr {print(')')} *
      | {print('(')} expr {print(') / (')} expr {print(')')} /
      | digit {print(digit)}
```

The translation seems pretty valid, but I can't figure out how to construct parse tree using that translation.

Can anyone explain me how to construct parse tree for `2 3 + 3 5 3 * - *` and `9 5 2 * -`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. `The translation seems pretty valid` can you please argue how parentheses are more useful with `*` and `/` than they are with `+` and `-`?

Comment: The above examples will translate into `(2+3) * (3 - (5)*(3))` and `9 - (5)*(2)` using that translation scheme. There is no need of parenthesis for simple digits as in `9 - (5)*(2)`. But for complex expressions as in the other example, parentheses is needed for multiplication and division. Again, adding parentheses for plus and minus also seems to be meaningful, but I don't think it is necessary since `9 - (5)*(2)` is same as `(9) - ((5)*(2))`.

Comment: `above examples will translate into (2+3) * (3 - (5)*(3)) and …` I get `(2+3*3-(5*3))`: go figure.

Comment: (Hint: you got binary operators, only. (Imagine a dash was allowed before a digit…))